# Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline."

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, soundcloud

When I try to connect to [soundcloud](/questions/tagged/soundcloud) using below code:

```
// Create the request.
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://soundcloud.com/api"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0];

// Create url connection and fire request
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

While I get below error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x14cfccae0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://soundcloud.com/api, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://soundcloud.com/api, kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline.}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://soundcloud.com/api, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://soundcloud.com/api, kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline.}
```

The Key is: I am running it on my iPhone, the network is 4G. The code is actually working well when I am using other network through Wifi.

Comment: have you tried other iPhone on 4G network? or just restart your iPhone sometimes it happens. Let me know if still is an issue

Comment: I restarted my iPhone, it won't work. I will call my friends to have some test on other network, will let you know the results. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, found the reason. Actually I tested using another iPhone, it just works well. Then when I try it using my iPhone, it still does not work.  And then, finally, I found that I turned off the network to the app on my iPhone. Sorry, guy.

Comment: haha it happens. Please mark my comment as useful it helped.

Comment: if user by mistake off the 4g network of App then how could we know that ??

Comment: I came across the same problem and your solution works. My question is how do I request for this permission programatically, or how do I check if the user had disabled it so I can notify him/her? Thanks.

Comment: did you checked that 4g internet data is enabled in device settings?

Answer (score 11):

The reason is the 4G network turned off for the app on my iPhone, not sure when and why I did it though.

Answer (score 2):

i found the solution its because you set timeoutInterval:10.0 
in

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://soundcloud.com/api"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0];
```

and response didn't get within this time, so all you need to exceed this time or you can also remove this interval

Answer (score 0):

Got the error removed by updating my MacOS...